# Unknown Issue With Google play Service?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I want to Use Google Drive in my application. I have tried that Demo Project from git- hub. I am getting Error of "Unknown Issue With Google play Service?".

It let me Select to choose Particular Account For Drive Use. But After That It gives me that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure why this is happening for the demo app, but for my own app that error was shown because the google drive android api had not been authorized. You could try creating your own project and use the demo project as a guide. Then, authorize your app by following the steps outlined here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

To add a client ID for your app, you need to have a project set up at https://code.google.com/apis/console/

You add the client id in the "Apis and Auth" section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried in my own application. But still it gives same error.Can you give your application code if it is possible.

Comment: Even if he did that, he can't provide you with his key to the project. You would have to modify the project with your own package name, apply for your own developer key, and debug any discrepancies. My guess would be that the end result would be the same and you'll get the same error once you modify your project the same way you modified the demo project. Instead, I'd suggest that you actually post your code to the demo you used, and describe the exact steps you've taken on the api console.